# Ruby yaml cannot read unicode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a settings.yml file for elasticsearch and need to inlcude this:

```
char_filter:
           arabic_normalization_extra:
               type: mapping
               mappings: [ "\x{670}=>ا", "ٰ=>ا", "ٱ=>ا", "آ=>ا", "ٖ=>ا" ]
```

Ruby throws an error and is very unhappy with this:

```
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected hexdecimal number while parsing a quoted scalar at line 9 column 28
```

How can I get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used yam extensively with unicode and it works pretty well.
This is what I use to load an utf-8 encoded file:

```
YAML::load(File.open(filepath, 'r:utf-8'))
```

Here you have an error when Ruby tries to parse `\x{670}`

`\x` is an escape sequence in ruby strings. It is used to represent a byte with a two digit hexadecimal number.

So an `\x` followed by an `{` is invalid and that's why ruby throws an error.

A working example is `\x67` which corresponds to `g`

I think a good question to ask yourself is why do you have those curly braces in your string? And what was the initial string before it was encoded in the yaml file.

Comment: It's the quotes that is not making it happy